# How to find Postgres/PHP deadlock in parallel updates?

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, database-deadlocks

So, I have an online game running PHP / PostgreSQL and one of the update processes is occasionally giving me deadlogs, like this:

> [2016-02-16 06:35:14] app.ERROR: Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An
>   exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE PlayerCharacter SET
>   spotting_distance = ?, visibility = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [2167,
>   20, 128]: SQLSTATE[40P01]: Deadlock detected: 7 ERROR:  deadlock
>   detected DETAIL:  Process 11691 waits for ShareLock on transaction
>   4173974; blocked by process 11706. Process 11706 waits for ShareLock
>   on transaction 4173977; blocked by process 11691. HINT:  See server
>   log for query details.

I've tried looking into the server logs, but it doesn't help.

The problem is that I have no idea how this happens, because while I can see the exact row in the code that causes it, I don't understand how it happens.

The code updates a large number of rows, which is why I've split the processing into 6 parallel processes, each one updating a subset of the total. In other words: No other process should be updating the row with the primary ID 128. So why is there a deadlock?

I suspect a) something strange or b) a bug in my scheduling code and some other process **is** updating row #128.

How can I find out what's going on? Can I convince Doctrine or Postgres to show me the blocking transaction? Can I somehow make the transaction non-blocking (since these are parallel processes using the same math, the result should be the same anyway, and if for whatever reason it isn't, I'd rather have a result that's off by a few percent than a deadlock).

Comment: `which is why I've split the processing into 6 parallel processes,` Don't do that, you probably don't need it. The deadlock *could* be caused by code fired by a trigger or even a "cascading" foreign key.

Comment: Trust me, I do need it. I'm doing a lot of expensive calculations and on just one CPU the processing time for a game turn exceeds 30 minutes.

If a foreign key is responsible (I don't use triggers), how can I find out which one?

Comment: If you are doing expensive calculations: based on which data? Data from the same table(s)?

Comment: Yes, data from this table plus a few others joined in.